# ANSI C download a file from a server

Tags: c

I try to download a tar file from a remote webserver, but I get only false data. Every runtime an other bytesize and with a HTTP header:

```
  //now it is time to receive the page
  memset(buf, 0, sizeof(buf));
  FILE *fp;

  if ((fp = fopen(FILENAME, "wb"))==NULL) {
        perror("Error open file");
  }
  else {
      while((tmpres = recv(xmlsock, buf, 65536, 0)) > 0){
          fwrite(buf, sizeof(buf), 1, fp);
          memset(buf, 0, tmpres);
      }
  } 
  if(tmpres < 0) {
      perror("Error receiving data");
  }

  fclose(fp);
  close(xmlsock);
```

My sent header is:

```
GET /updates/xxxxx.tar HTTP/1.1
Host: www.yyyyyyyy.de
User-Agent: HTMLGET 1.1
Connection: close
```

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
fwrite(buf, 1, tmpres, fp);
```

You're always writing `sizeof(buf)` bytes in your original code, but you only read `tmpres` bytes, so you're writing a lot of cruft every time (there is no guarantee how big the packets are that you receive and in how many recv calls your data will be split up)

Answer (score 0):

Two problems: The first is that you write the complete buffer to the file even if not all of it was filled by the `recv` Call. The other problem is that you receive everything, without regards to the [HyperText Transfer Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) which naturally includes headers.

For the first problem the solution is very simple, as you already have a variable whose value is the amount of data received.

For the second problem, you need to learn [HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) and how it separates the headers and the data.